# Impedance matching with RF-attenuator

Tags: rf, impedance, impedance-matching, attenuator

I want to use an RF-attenuator to impedance match a transmission line that goes from a 5GHz signal generator to a (potentially high-Z) device. The goal is not to get optimal power transmission but rather to prevent damage of the signal generator caused by reflections. Is it better to use the attenuator at the begiinig on the transmission line or at the end of the transmission line? Will there be a substantial difference in signal integrity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of power levels are you talking about ?

Comment: input power to the transmission line will be 2 dBm (800mV/pp) and the attenuator will be 20dB.

Comment: I'd put it at the end of the transmission line, right before the impedance discontinuity, otherwise the reflection will travel back and forth the transmission line. If you are building the attenuator yourself you can also add proper termination (effectively, the high-impedance device becomes a voltage probe then).

Comment: @SimonRichter Okay, that makes perfect sense to me! Thanks!

Comment: @quantumphilip, if you have access to a network analyzer you might want to check the return loss (S11) at the input of your transmission line, with the attenuator at either end, but with the load disconnected. You'll get a good idea of the amount of missmatch you're really getting in the frequency band of interest, in both of your cases.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it better to use the attenuator at the begining on the transmission
> line or at the end of the transmission line? Will there be a
> substantial difference in signal integrity?*

Place it at the beginning.

**Reason 1:** if you put it at the end of the line, the high load impedance won't necessarily be matched to the attenuator and this will cause the input impedance of the attenuator to be badly defined. As a consequence the attenuator won't present the right impedance to the t-line and you'll get an unattenuated reflection back to the signal generator.

**Reason 2:** if you put it at the beginning of the t-line, you'll **(a)** be matching the interface between signal generator and t-line and **(b)**, the unwanted reflection coming back from the "badly" terminated t-line will hit the correct impedance of the attenuator and **(c)**, if anything gets through, it will be attenuated by the attenuator. Belt and braces.

Comment: RE "The high load impedance won't necessarily be matched...", that's true with the attenuator at the beginning of the line as well. The t-line with a high Z at the far end will also look like a high-reflection load (with uncertainty about the phase of the reflection unless you do some careful measurements first). So either way the attenuator won't look like a perfect match at its input.

Comment: That said, I've always seen matching pads placed near the generator, so I don't think it's wrong to do that.

Comment: @ThePhoton if the attenuator is at the beginning of the line, any reflections will hit "the right impedance" and be absorbed in the attenuator (mainly). That's the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: That's true if the attenuator is at the far end also.